# How do I create a dynamic class with variable name of type 'toString'?

Tags: c#

Thank you for reading my article.

I am using a `UserControl` of asp.net in company webpage.
`UserControl` can not use inheritance class, because that already inherits `System.Web.UI.UserControl` class.

So I want to create a dynamic class with the name of the parent page.

Below is my code.

```
string userNo = string.Empty;
string virtualPath = Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath.ToString();
virtualPath = virtualPath.Substring(virtualPath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);

//I want to use the generated class by referring to the variable name of "virtualPath" in the "here" text below.
//userNo = Uact.Framework.Common.Decryptor.Decrypt((("here!")Context.Handler).UserNo);

switch (virtualPath.ToUpper().Trim()){
    case "PROJECTSIGNWRITE.ASPX" :
        userNo = Uact.Framework.Common.Decryptor.
                    Decrypt(((ProjectSignWrite)Context.Handler).UserNo);
        break;

    case "PROJECTREPORTVIEW.ASPX" :
        userNo = Uact.Framework.Common.Decryptor.
                    Decrypt(((ProjectReportView)Context.Handler).UserNo);
        break;

    case "PROJECTCOMPLETE.ASPX" :
        userNo = Uact.Framework.Common.Decryptor.
                    Decrypt(((ProjectComplete)Context.Handler).UserNo);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Chances are you don't want to use dynamic classes. I've been working as a C# developer close to 10 years, and only once have I been tempted to use dynamic classes.

Comment: First advice for a newbie, please mention clearly what you really want to do and why? what issue you faced? Otherwise, people cannot help you. We don't know what you are trying to accomplish, there might be a very easy standard solution for it that you don't know.

Comment: Thank you for your interest.
I am still immature in English. So I have not been able to write my situation for a long time now.
Website which I administer is inherited "basePage" of framework. but, some pages inherit the user control "System.Web.UI.UserControl".
At this time, The value that I want have in top-level inheritance page "basePage". 
I wanted to bring that value but I could not dynamically create the class. So I was request your helping.
Thank you for your interest my first article. And I will do to study programing harder. 
Good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using inheritance, use an interface.

Declare an interface with the property UserNo

```
public interface IHasUserNo
{
     string UserNo {get; set;}
}
```

Then have your classes like for example `ProjectSignWrite` implement this interface.

```
public class ProjectSignWrite : UserControl, IHasUserNo
{
    .....
}
```

You can then simply write:

```
userNo = Uact.Framework.Common.Decryptor.Decrypt(((IHasUserNo)Context.Handler).UserNo);
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest.
I am still immature in English. So I have not been able to write my situation for a long time now.
Website which I administer is inherited "basePage" of framework. but, some pages inherit the user control "System.Web.UI.UserControl".
At this time, The value that I want have in top-level inheritance page "basePage". 
I wanted to bring that value but I could not dynamically create the class. So I was request your helping.
Thank you for your interest my first article. And I will do to study programing harder. 
Good luck to you!